# Select From View | Order By Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have one view named [AccountsLedger] with a date field name [Date].
When I use this query, the order by does not work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,[Date],103) as [Date]
                          ,[VoucherType]
                          ,[BillNo]
                          ,[Debit]
                          ,[Credit]
                      FROM [AccountsLedger]
                      order by [Date]
```

Results:

```
Date    VoucherType BillNo  Debit   Credit
01/06/2011  SALE    18  8400.00 0.00
03/06/2011  BEEJAK  15  0.00    24944.40
12/12/2009  PAYMENT 1   1000.00 0.00
12/12/2011  JOURNAL 1   800.00  0.00
12/12/2012  RECEIPT 4   0.00    1200.00
12/12/2016  RECEIPT 5   0.00    600.00
```

Please help.

Comment: Date values are perhaps best localized/formatted in the front end rather than SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,[Date],103) as [Date]
                      ,[VoucherType]
                      ,[BillNo]
                      ,[Debit]
                      ,[Credit]
FROM [AccountsLedger]
ORDER by [AccountsLedger].[Date]
```

The problem is that your query is sorting by newly formed string value, that you named the same way as you datetime field is named in the table. So, in order to fix the issue you need to have different names for the result string value and the underlying field or specify table prefix.

Comment: +1 - This is the correct identification of the problem however the solution is to simply apply the table prefix in the order by. I.e., Just use `[AccountsLedger].[Date]` instead of just `[Date]`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the your field is of varchar type, not date. Try like this instead:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,[Date],103) as [Date]
                          ,[VoucherType]
                          ,[BillNo]
                          ,[Debit]
                          ,[Credit]
                      FROM [AccountsLedger]
                      order by CONVERT(varchar,[Date],102)
```